# swift: edit text in JSON

Tags: ios, swift

I have JSON file with text and label. In JSON file I want to add this characters `<b>` or `<i>` to some words. For example:

```
"this is my text <b>bold<b> or <i>italic<i>"
```

And before when I show text in label I want to analyse my text and if some words have this characters `<b>` or `<i>` I want to make this word bold or italic in the text of the label. How to do it? Or there are another way to make bold text from JSON?

UPDATE:

Yours code:

```
/* Set Tagged Text & Fonts */
let taggedTextString = myText.text
let tagFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
let normalFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)

/* You can simply assign the AttributedText to the modified String, which may return nil. */
textLabel.attributedText = taggedTextString.modifyFontWithTags(openingTag: "<tag>", closingTag: "</tag>", taggedFont: tagFont, unTaggedFont: normalFont)
```

My code:

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myText.text)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
textLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Is this code the best way to union your and my code?

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: allTagsSplitArray.count, by: 1) {
finalAttrStr.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: allTagsSplitArray[i], attributes: [kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey : i % 2 == 0 ? untaggedTextFont : taggedTextFont]))

// my code

finalAttrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttrStr.length))
        }
```

Comment: Please add some of the code you tried and read up on the documentation of `NSAttributedString` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring), it is a little ancient and verbose, but not bad enough to merit a Swift variant (yet...).

Comment: Take a look at this [handy extension](https://github.com/GorowskiZac/ZGTaggedText) I wrote for doing something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I seem to have accomplished this is by running through the string and scanning for your key tags - `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.

To make things easier (and more reusable), we should make an `extension` of our `String` or `NSAttributedString` classes. For this example, I've extended the `String` class, and and I return a `NSAttributedString`:

```
func modifyFontWithTags(openingTag: String, closingTag: String, taggedFont: UIFont?, unTaggedFont: UIFont?) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    /* Make sure we have everything we need. */
    guard let taggedTextFont = taggedFont,
        let untaggedTextFont = unTaggedFont,
        !self.isEmpty,
        self.contains(openingTag),
        self.contains(closingTag) else { return nil }
    /* Split the string up using our closing tag. */
    let closingTagSplitArray = self.components(separatedBy: closingTag)
    /* Make a placeholder array. */
    var allTagsSplitArray = [String]()
    /* Iterate through our split array. */
    for item in closingTagSplitArray {
        if item.contains(openingTag) {
            /* Strip the opening tag & append. */
            allTagsSplitArray.append(contentsOf: item.components(separatedBy: openingTag))
        } else {
            /* Just append. */
            allTagsSplitArray.append(item)
        }
    }
    /* Instantiate our attributed string. */
    let finalAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: allTagsSplitArray.count, by: 1) {
        /* Add our font to every-other item in the array (the tagged portions). */
        finalAttrStr.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: allTagsSplitArray[i], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : i % 2 == 0 ? untaggedTextFont : taggedTextFont]))
    }

    return finalAttrStr
}
```

Note: In this example, I take in an `UIFont` parameter, but you can modify this function to take in whatever attribute types you want.

Comment: It is work but I can't use my code(I updated code in my question) with yours. How to fix it?